# component factory krypton myexe.exe has stopped

Tags: c#, dll, components, krypton-toolkit

well i am working with Component.Factory.Toolkit.dll this works in my machine which i have installed component factory, but when I copy the Bin folder in ohter pc then this does not work and InitializeComponent(); is not execute! a simple windows form using this  toolkit cant start if I execute in other machine.Do i need to install component.factory.toolkit in this pc?

Now i have connect to a remote equipe, i call the exe from my machine  since this new pc, and i got the same error 
"exe has stopped"

how can i execute it? i dont want to install the tookit in every PC need uses this application.

Comment: Here is an [***Answer***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996201/can-krypton-toolkit-run-on-other-computers-without-toolkit-installed/23016421#23016421) to a simliar question

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to install Krypton toolkit on ever PC, Just include **ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.dll** with your Setup/Bin file(s).

Also here is an [***Answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996201/can-krypton-toolkit-run-on-other-computers-without-toolkit-installed/23016421#23016421) to a simliar question