# Can krypton toolkit run on other computers without toolkit installed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, krypton-toolkit

As I said in the title, I have Krypton ToolKit downloaded on one computer, but am submitting a project using the toolkit to be graded by a professor who almost certainly does not have it. My question will he be able to run it?

Comment: Just make sure the krypton toolkit dll's are in your project's bin and referenced correctly.

Comment: Is that done within visual studios or by directly moving the dll's into the bin folder? Thanks for the quick response by the way!

Comment: If you installed the toolkit via Nuget, everything should be set for you already. If you downloaded the toolkit manually then add the dll's  to your project's bin folder and reference them from your bin folder within visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which Krypton controls you are using in the project.
The most used krypton DLL is:

```
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.dll
```

Check your project references and see which krypton DLLs have included there. Also if you set the property "Copy Local" to "True" for Krypton reference(s) and build the project then you will get them in your Bin directory.
The other Krypton DLLs which maybe necessary for your project (if included):

```
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Design.dll
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Docking.dll
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.dll
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Ribbon.dll
ComponentFactory.Krypton.Workspace.dll
```

These DLLs exist in:

```
%YourProgramFiles%\Component Factory\Krypton Toolkit (Version)\Bin
```

Finally make sure that your professor has the .NET Framework to be able to run your program.